# Unable to explicitly set domain for document in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, iframe, cross-domain

Currently I have the document.domain to be `www.xyz.com` and I wanted to change it to `www.abc.com` for which I wrote the below code.

```
 document.domain = new_domain      // where new_domain="www.abc.com"
```

Works for all the browsers except IE, where it shows **invalid argument error** for the above statement

I even tried to use **.postMessage** but no success.

This seems to be kinda stopper for me to load my **iframe** which I have already created in the DOM with height and width as 0. And use the below code to set the **src**

```
CI_jQuery('#print-frame').attr('srcdoc', data);
CI_jQuery('#print-frame').attr('sandbox', 'allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-modals allow-forms allow-downloads');
```

where **data is the complete html content for the iframe** and **CI_jQuery = jQuery**

Comment: I'm pretty sure `document.domain` is an immutable property

Comment: Any workarounds for this?

Comment: becoz I have a need to change the domain for my case

Comment: Try using `Object.defineProperty(document, 'domain', { value: 'my-value' })`?

Comment: Why do you need to change an immutable property in the first place? Sounds like an XY problem

Comment: @evolutionxbox In my case, should it be Object.defineProperty(document, 'domain', { value: 'www.abc.com' }) ?

Comment: @evolutionxbox In my case....is that .............Object.defineProperty(document, 'domain', { value: 'www.abc.com' }) ??

Comment: Try it out and see. It looks correct, but only you can check to see if it works

Comment: Yes that removed the error but still the iframe is not showing up